# A suggestion of good book

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Please anyone suggest me a good book which have theory of "Hilbert–Schmidt and Trace Class Operators".

Comment: A better title for your question would be "What is a good book for the Hilbert–Schmidt theorem and Trace Class Operators." Also, you should add the tag 'reference request.'

Comment: Please also some information on your background: Do you want to learn the basics (as they are covered in almost any introductory functional analysis book) or are you already familiar with them and want to learn things in more depths?

Comment: modrate level sir